# HTML5 CSS and Rails template

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html

I am using the free HTML5 template at the following URL:

http://html5up.net/eventually

I can not get the background images working from the `main.js` file. (`bg01.jpg`, `bg02.jpg`, `bg03.jpg`).

How should I reference these image files using rails asset pipeline assumign they are in /assets/ ?

The CSS and layout is working fine, my includes currently look like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'main', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'main', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

The above is to include the CSS and JS that comes with the eventually template, but I don't get the 3 rotating images in the background.

Any helps would be great.

Thanks

Comment: show the relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes... You have to use the asset pipeline.

You can reference the images by adding the following to the image address reference:

```
<%= asset_path 'bg01.jpg' %>
```

for this tag to work in a css file, you have to change the file name adding a `.erb` to its end. It would became `yourFile.css.erb`  or `yourfile.scss.erb`

#### update

your code goes like this:

```
images: {
        'images/bg01.jpg': 'center',
        'images/bg02.jpg': 'center',
        'images/bg03.jpg': 'center'
        },
```

should be changed to

```
images: {
        '<%= asset_path 'bg01.jpg' %>': 'center',
        '<%= asset_path 'bg02.jpg' %>': 'center',
        '<%= asset_path 'bg03.jpg' %>': 'center'
        },
```

Comment: does this work for javascript files? If you look at main.js in the template it references three images inside an array, confusing me.

Comment: the same way =).. you have to rename the file to `.js.erb`

Comment: I cant get it working when the JS references the images like this:     var settings = {

     // Images (in the format of 'url': 'alignment').
      images: {
       'assets/bg01.jpg': 'center',
       'assets/g02.jpg': 'center',
       'assets/bg03.jpg': 'center'
      },

     // Delay.
      delay: 6000

    };

Comment: 1. rename the file to `main.js.erb`;   2. the strings `'assets/bg01.jpg':` shoud be replaced with `'<%= asset_path 'bg01.jpg' %>'`

Comment: I have done exactly both those steps, still not working.

Comment: did you recompile your assets? the site you shared still have your initial version...

Comment: Thanks for all the help!